# How to trigger function in child component ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to triger child function inside parent component? I am using React

Parent component ->

```
selectedColors = (colors) => { 
   // need to props colors and trigger child function.
  };


    <Field
      id="primary-color"
      name="theme.primaryColor"
      component={ButtonColorPicker} 
     />
```

Child component is **ButtonColorPicker**

ButtonColorPicker component ->

```
  handleChange = (color) => {
    console.log("here i need props value from PARENT", color);
    this.props.input.onChange(color.hex);
  };

 <SketchPicker color={input.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

import { SketchPicker } from "react-color";

SketchPicker is just plugin for changing colors.

I need from parent component to trigger handleChange function.

Comment: Put the handle function into your parent component an pass it to your child as a prop

Comment: I can;t because in child component i have some properties which i don;t have in parent

Comment: that's okay, just pass the function as a said, then you can call it inside your child component using the values you need from it

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

First, create a state that will determine when the function will be triggered.

`const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false)`

Now you pass `trigger` to your children component, and inside it you can create a `useEffect` with `trigger` inside your dependency array that will call your function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // children function to be triggered is here.
}, [trigger])
```

Now, everytime you change your `trigger` state on parent component, the children function will be triggered.

On your parent component, you can do something like

```
selectedColors = (colors) => {
    setTrigger(true)

    // whatever you want.

    setTrigger(false)        
}
```

Comment: You *could* technically just pass the reference to the function as well.

Comment: I think the question title is missleading. If I understood it correctly, he wants to trigger a function from the children component, from an action inside parent.

Comment: Right. So the function actually lives in the parent context and is passed down to the child through props so *both* can call the function.

Comment: Oh ok, now I get what you are talking. I guess this is a better solution if you want both components to have control over the function trigger.

Comment: Ahhh friend, i am using class components :(